# Slider doesn't follow finger on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, range

I have been trying to create a before and after image slider using the range input type and JQuery. It all qorks perfectly fine on desktop, but when you try to move the slider on mobile, it will only move if you click where you want it to be, aka you can't drag it.
This is very annoying and I have spent a good hour trying to find a solution but to no avail.
I am using firefox browser, but I have tried this on Chrome mobile and the problem is still there. Infact, the slider completely disappears if you are on chrome mobile.

Steps to reproduce:
Open the inspect tab on [this](https://itscoolguy.github.io/carwash-website/) website, and then open mobile view and click the icon to enable touch control, as seen in the image below:
[instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvrZX.jpg)

If you try to drag the slider, it will not work, you can only click where you want it to go.

Here is my code:

```js
$("#slider").on("input change", (e) => {
  //console.log(e)
  const sliderPos = e.target.value;
  // Update the width of the foreground image
  $('#before-image').css('width', `${sliderPos}%`)
  // Update the position of the slider button
  $('.slider-button').css('left', `calc(${sliderPos}% - 18px)`)
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
}

#header-logo {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

#mobile-menu-button {
  margin-right: 17px;
}

#homepage-main-image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}

#homepage-main-image-container .comparison-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: 100vw 100%;
}

#homepage-main-image-container #after-image {
  background-image: url("https://itscoolguy.github.io/carwash-website/images/comparisons/comp_1/after.jpg");
}

#homepage-main-image-container #before-image {
  background-image: url("https://itscoolguy.github.io/carwash-website/images/comparisons/comp_1/before.jpg");
  width: 50%;
}

#homepage-main-image-container #slider {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.3);
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#homepage-main-image-container #slider:hover {
  background: rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.1);
}

#homepage-main-image-container #slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 6px;
  height: 99%;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#homepage-main-image-container #slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 6px;
  height: 99%;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#homepage-main-image-container .slider-button {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  left: calc(50% - 18px);
  top: calc(50% - 18px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#homepage-main-image-container .slider-button:after {
  content: "";
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid #5D5D5D;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#homepage-main-image-container .slider-button:before {
  content: "";
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid #5D5D5D;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="header-left">
    <nav></nav>
  </div>
  <did id="header-right">
    <button id="mobile-menu-button">
    <img src="https://itscoolguy.github.io/carwash-website/images/icon-menu.svg" alt="" id="mobile-menu-image">
    </button>
  </did>
</header>
<main>
  <div id="homepage-main-image-container">
    <div id="main-homepage-image">
      <div id="after-image" class="comparison-image"></div>
      <div id="before-image" class="comparison-image"></div>
      <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" name='slider' id="slider" autocomplete="off">
      <div class='slider-button'></div>
      <div id="test"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Yogi I'm sorry but I can't seem to find any css, html or js that has `display: none` in it. Did you perhaps mean `appearance: none`? If so, removing these lines does not change anything for me. Thank you for the response though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer, I have settled on using Juxtapose JS, which is a "library" of sorts that allows you to create very clean looking image comparisons. Here is their website for anyone interested: https://juxtapose.knightlab.com/

When you enter the parameters in the website, it simply gives you an iFrame to copy in, but if you go to the SRC url you can copy over parts to your project, which is what I did, due to the fact that I don't like not being able to edit styles and such.

As for the origional question, I haven't found a feasible solution with 5+ hours of searching, so I think this is the best answer for the question.